# MS Access vba .InitialFileName = Path & "\"

Tags: vba, path

```
Path = "Z:\Ebay\Suppliers Inventory\" & Fnumber & "\" & Fname & "\"
```

It works up to the last (& "\") then the Path will fail.  My SKU is (XXX-000001) not sure if the dash is the problem and would be a pain to fix at this late date.

```
 Dim objFSO As Object
 Dim objFile As Object
 Dim openDialog As FileDialog
 Dim Path As String
 Dim GetPath As String
 Dim Filename As String
 Dim GetFileName As String
 Dim Fname As String
 Dim Fnumber As String
Fnumber = Me.FolderNumber
Fname = [SKU]
Path = "Z:\Ebay\Suppliers Inventory\" & Fnumber & "\" & Fname & "\"

Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
openDialog.InitialFileName = Path
openDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
openDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
        If openDialog.Show Then
        GetFileName = openDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        GetFileName = ""
    End If
Forms![Items to List].ImageGroup.Form.PicText = GetFileName
Me.Image2 = GetFileName
```

Comment: what is the error and is this a share drive? Assuming this is Windows

Comment: Your code looks correct. Issue a `?dir(Path & "*.*")` in the immediate window after `Path = ...` to see if it returns anything.

Comment: QHarr- The error is the Path defaults to a previous Path and doesn't change when Fnumber changes. This is a shared network drive connected to my router. But it doesn't have to be if that is the problem.          AcsEmco-  I get nothing if I use the path as above.  If I comment out any of the parts of the Path including the last &"\"  I get:  
 Href link for listings.txt   which is a text file I use for my listings, but it is on my C:\  drive...   I will change my code to use my local drive and will report back.  Thank you both for your time.

Comment: No change with using C:\.  I did get a Run-time error 52: Bad file name or number,  in the immediate window .

Comment: I finally got it to work.  I pointed my Fname to my Form!SKU1  instead of my Table [SKU].  Not sure why it works, but it does....  Thanks again QHarr and AcsErno (will save your code) for your time.